# How to install server JRE in windows7 64 bit?

Tags: java

1. I downloaded server-jre-7u21-windows-x64.tar.gz from the link

   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html
2. Unzipped the .gz file and got file
   server-jre-7u21-windows-x64 without extension.
3. I tried to install it by just double click. But unable to install?

   Can anybody suggest me how to do this?

Comment: did you get any error????? But unable to install should have a meaning?

Comment: Go through installation guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/

Comment: I would like to make it clear. I am unable to proceed. if it is exe or jar file , we can proceed...but there is no extension...how can be installed.

Comment: what kind of error message do you get?

Comment: when i double click the file and try to install, it asks choose program to open it. But i am do not see any appropriate program to open.

Comment: it's not an archive, not an executable. Extract the files, set the environment variables.

Answer (score 11):

OP probably already solved, but for others, I had the same problem- for some reason the file downloads as:
server-jre-7u21-windows-x64.gz

When you extract it, you just get the tar file without an extension.  Attempting to extract the tar (using 7-zip in my case) gives you invalid output (empty folders).

To fix, just rename the downloaded file to:
server-jre-7u21-windows-x64.tar.gz

Extracting the gz then the tar should get you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK All you do is unpack it into a directory which you add to your path *(the Path Environmental Variable)*.

I would make sure you have a utility which can untar files.